# How pass empty string if key not found in list of dict

Tags: python, dictionary

i have dictionary

```
myd = {
  'Items': [{'key':2}
    
  ],
  'Count': 1, 
  'RetryAttempts': 0
  }
```

I m printing the key with below

`print(myd['Items'][0].get('key'))`

I have dictionary which 'Items' is empty

```
myd = {
  'Items': [
    
  ],
  'Count': 0, 
  'RetryAttempts': 0
  }
```

If I try with `print(a['Items'][0].get('key'))` I m getting index out of range error

Is there any i can do in list comprehension, if key is not present then need to get `empty string` or `None`

Comment: `print(a['Items'][0].get('key') if a['Items'] else None)`

Comment: If the  `Items` key can be unset when it is empty, then for the same effect you could also do: `if a.get('Items') else None`